# $\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} +_{\mathscr{C}} \kappa = \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}$ where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving the following formula:

> $\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} +_{\mathscr{C}} \kappa = \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}$, where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}$ is cardinal exponential, $+_{\mathscr{C}}$ is cardinal addition.

The left-hand side of the formula can be expanded as below:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} +_{\mathscr{C}} \kappa &= \operatorname{Card}\left(\boldsymbol{2}\right)^{\operatorname{Card}\left(\kappa\right)} +_{\mathscr{C}} \operatorname{Card}\left(\kappa\right)\\
&= \operatorname{Card}\left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}\right) +_{\mathscr{C}} \operatorname{Card}\left(\kappa\right)\\
&= \operatorname{Card}\left(\left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}\times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\kappa \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right)\right)\\
&\approx \left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\kappa \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and similarly, we have
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \approx \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa},
\end{equation*}
where the second $\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}$ is the set of all functions from $\kappa$ to $\boldsymbol{2}$.

To finish the proof, we have to establish $\left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\kappa \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right) \approx \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}$. To establish $\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \preceq \left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\kappa \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right)$ is pretty straightforward, but how should we come up with the reverse? I guess we have to utilize the property that $\kappa$ is infinite. Can anyone help establish
\begin{equation}
\left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\kappa \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right) \preceq \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa}?
\end{equation}

Comment: $$(2^\kappa\times\{0\})\cup(\kappa\times\{1\})\preceq(2^\kappa\times\{0\})\cup(2^\kappa\times\{1\})$$ How does that last set compare with $2^{\kappa+1}$?

Comment: It seems that $\left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right) \approx \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa + \boldsymbol{1}}$. Then $\left(\boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\kappa \times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right) \preceq \boldsymbol{2}^{\kappa + \boldsymbol{1}}$.

Comment: And $\kappa+1\approx\kappa$, so $2^{\kappa+1}\approx 2^\kappa$.

Comment: I see. This is where the proof uses the property that $\kappa$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, whenever we have two infinite cardinals $A$ and $B$, we have $A +_{\mathscr{C}} B = \max(A, B)$. So in this case, since $2^\kappa > \kappa$, we have $2^\kappa +_{\mathscr{C}} \kappa = 2^\kappa$.

Comment: Seems that you used the absorption theorem of cardinal arithmetic.